# How to skip the terminal update installing progress when the updates is in progress on the unwanted application

Tags: apt, updates

I want to skip the terminal update installing progress when the updates is in progress on the unwanted application 
[image]

without removing the source repository from source list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to update one application and skip all other updates, run:

```
sudo apt-get install [package-name]
```

Otherwise, if you want to exclude one package from being updated, follow the instructions from [How to forbid updating of a specific package?](https://askubuntu.com/q/18654/6969#18656).